# WF 4.0 can't get to resume workflow on the staging/production environment

Tags: asp.net, workflow-foundation-4, production-environment

I have developed various registeration workflows using WF4.0. Each work flow has various bookmarks. I am using the registeration wf for an asp.net application.

I tested the asp.net application locally and it is working fine( Starting WF, Persisting to db and resuming bookmarks). When I try to test it on the staging server, everything goes messy. I can no longer resume wfs and I get an error message :

> System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.InstancePersistenceCommandException
>   was unhandled by user code   Message=The execution of the
>   InstancePersistenceCommand named
>   {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:System.Activities.Persistence/command}LoadWorkflow
>   was interrupted by an error.   Source=System.Runtime.DurableInstancing
>   StackTrace:
>          at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
>          at System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.InstancePersistenceContext.OuterExecute(InstanceHandle
>   initialInstanceHandle, InstancePersistenceCommand command, Transaction
>   transaction, TimeSpan timeout)
>          at System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.InstanceStore.Execute(InstanceHandle
>   handle, InstancePersistenceCommand command, TimeSpan timeout)
>          at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.PersistenceManager.Load(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>          at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.LoadCore(TimeSpan timeout, Boolean loadAny)
>          at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.Load(Guid instanceId, TimeSpan timeout)
>          at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.Load(Guid instanceId)
>          at CEO_StartUpCEORegisterationTest.LoadInstance(Guid wfInstanceId) in c:\Users\Kunoichi\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\CMERegistrationSystem\RegistrationPortal\CEO\StartUpCEORegisterationTest.aspx.cs:line
>   64
>          at CEO_StartUpCEORegisterationTest.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Kunoichi\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\CMERegistrationSystem\RegistrationPortal\CEO\StartUpCEORegisterationTest.aspx.cs:line
>   44
>          at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
>          at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
>          at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   InnerException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>          Message=Index 'NCIX_KeysTable_SurrogateInstanceId' on table 'KeysTable' (specified in the FROM clause) does not exist.
>          Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
>          ErrorCode=-2146232060
>          Class=16
>          LineNumber=211
>          Number=308
>          Procedure=LoadInstance
>          Server=
>          State=1
>          StackTrace:
>               at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
>               at System.Activities.DurableInstancing.SqlWorkflowInstanceStoreAsyncResult.SqlCommandAsyncResultCallback(IAsyncResult
>   result)

I know that this is quite verbose. But I have been banging my head against the wall for more than a week. I did search and all I came to know was to work on ms dtc. I enabled it on the staging server , I installed application server on the staging server and I am still getting the same error. I would appreciate if anyone could help with the problem. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hi, Build a sample asp.net application and try to access workflow instance store database. It that accessing with the same crediantial that you used with workflow persistance setting? Epmty Instance store database and redeply wf assembly.

Answer (score 1):

Who created the persistence store being used on the staging server?  What schema was used to create it?  Look for differences between the scripts used locally and in production.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out :)) seems like the scripts ran were different. Thanx for ur reply (Y)

Comment: you took the words right out of my mouth and I'm not even sure how that happened.  If you use the AppFabric configuration application it creates/updates the database for you.